# Annotation or implementation for toString(), equals() and hashCode() methods?

Tags: java, annotations, tostring, lombok

I have seen the following implementation in a repository and I am confused:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {

    // properties

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return super.equals(other);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it logical to implement these methods as they are already implemented in the base class? Is it unnecessary to implement `hashCode()`, `equals()` methods here and adding `@ToString(callSuper = true)` to the beginning of the entity class?
2. For adding these methods in the entity, is it better to use annotation instead of adding 3-4 lines code for each method?
3. I think there is a misuse regarding to these methods. Because 2 of them are implemented and one of them (`toString`) is added via annotation. I think all of them should be used in the same manner (all of them via annotation or all of them via implementation). Am I wrong?

Comment: Does anybody else has no experience on Spring or Spring Boot?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam CHICO? Any reply pls?

Comment: The annotations are part of lombok, not spring or spring boot. These annotations are used to reduce the code and have default implementations if you have implemented the don't have the annotations. Note I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you should implement them also in the child classes. The reason is that you have additional properties on them that should be taken into account on both `hashCode()` and `equals()`.
2. That is a matter of personal opinion. Some people like to have full control over the code, some are happy to write less code and rely on dependencies such as lombok. I would use the annotations. If you need something more complex, then you can always write the methods yourself.
3. If you have the annotation you shouldn't have the method implemented or your own, unless you want to avoid the annotation to do his job. Generally speaking, if you are ok with the annotations, you should stick to that. The important thing is to be consistent so that code is readable.

Comment: Perfect explanatónsç many thanks. Regarding to **#3**, I think my approach is correct (we should stick to annotation for all of 3 methods or implementation for all of 3 methods)?

Comment: Amigo??? Any reply por favor?

Comment: Exactly, you should select one approach and go with it. I would go with the annotations.

Comment: @Alex do you still have any questions?

Comment: Perfecto!!! Voted up and marked as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The annotations you are using like "Getter Setter NoArgsConstructor ToString" belong to lombok.
In your case, I think use lombok's @Data annotation is a better way.

> @Data is like having implicit @Getter, @Setter, @ToString,
> @EqualsAndHashCode and @RequiredArgsConstructor annotations on the
> class.

Note that if your entity has superclass, then mostly you should set parameter callSuper=true to  @ToString and @EqualsAndHashCode.
You can refer [Lombok data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) for further information.

Comment: Thanks a lot chico, voted up ;)